# How to count lines in Bash's PS2 variable?

Tags: bash

I am trying to teach my PS2 variable to show the line number of the current multiline command, it should look like this:

```
user@host $ echo "this is
 02> a command which is
 03> wrapped over multiple lines."
```

So I tried this inside my `.bashrc`:

```
export LCNT=1
PS1="`LCNT=1`\u@\h \$ "
PS2=" `LCNT=$((LCNT + 1)) && printf -- %02d $LCNT`> "
```

which should increment the counter `LCNT` with every further line of a multiline command and reset it back to 1 when starting a new command. But since the output of LCNT is always 2 its increment is obviously not saved back into the global variable. Is there a better (like working) approach to achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124904/67134

Comment: The problem with your approach, in a nutshell, is subshells. The link above talks about this in some detail.

Comment: thanks, I had to abandon the use of the printf function to get the leading zeros, but with slight modifications( I used " instead of ') I got it now running

Comment: What did you end up with?

Comment: `LCNT=1`
`PS1="\${LCNT##*[\$((LCNT=1))-9]}\u@\h \$ "`
`PS2=" \$((LCNT=LCNT+1))> "`

Comment: So exactly what is in the answer I linked then only with more escaping since you use `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: yes, you're right. Only more escaping. Use of ' would have required fixing on some other functions I already use in PS1 and PS2

Comment: You have functions you run during the setting of the `PS1`/`PS2` values? That is not each time they are evaluated by the shell but once when you set them in your shell init? Because otherwise they are all already quoted this way or not working as intended.

Comment: The problems have been with the variables which are unquoted. Now this is my complete PS1: 
`PS1="\${LCNT##*[\$((LCNT=1))-9]}${BGREEN}\u${NORMAL}@${BPURPLE}\h${NORMAL}:${BBLUE}\w\$(__ret_val ' ${BRED}[%d]')\$(__git_ps1 ' ${BYELLOW}[%s]')\$(__svn_ps1 ' [%d]' '${BYELLOW}' '${BRED}')${BYELLOW}\$${NORMAL} "` with __ret_val, __svn_ps1 being self written functions and $BRED, etc some colors.

Comment: Ah, so yeah, you've got escaped functions everywhere to allow for immediate colors. Is that necessary though. Single quoting the whole thing, even the colors, should work correctly I think. Though that will complicate the embedded single quotes a bit (needing `'\''` for each embedded one to work).